# difference between two images

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-figure

On Matlab I have two BIN image. Can I computing difference of gray scale pixel by pixel and show it on the histogram?
(The images have same size)

Comment: are they binary or greyscale?

Comment: So then `sum(imageA & ~imageB)` and `sum(~imageA & imageB)`

Comment: and then? For show it on histogram?

Comment: just plot the numbers as a bar chart using `bar`, `bar([sum(imageA & ~imageB), sum(~imageA & imageB)])`

Comment: Are you sure that is correct? in the plot return value 0, but the two images are different

Comment: Sorry it should be `imageA(:)`, `imageB(:)` etc... it works for me

Comment: Are you guys trying to histogram a binary image that is to plot two counts for 0s and 1s? Do you really need this kind of visualization instead of just sum(a)/255 or something?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider `imshowpair` . Display a pair of grayscale images.

```
A = imread('PIX.tif');
B = imrotate(A,5,'bicubic','crop');

imshowpair(A,B,'diff');
```

other method as described over here. [comparing two image using histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475815/comparing-two-image-using-histogram)

Comment: My images are double type. imshowpair doesn't support this input

Comment: If your images are truly binary (0/1), you can convert them from double to something that `imshowpair` supports without losing any info, though.